# Doing while loop properly until "0" input to stop the loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I need help. I'm currently learning C++ programming and I'm still at the beginner level. I'm still figuring out how to make the while loop working. My idea is when inserting the correct *code* input, the switch statement choose the right case statement and loop back to insert another input until *0* inserted to stop the loop and calculate for the final output in *main()* constructor.

I know I have few kinks to fix soon but I'm still struggling to figure out this particular part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

double sst = 0.06, total = 0, grandTotal, price, discount, newPrice, totalSST;
int quantity, count, code;
string name, ech;

void item001(){
    name = "Rice (5kg)";
    price = 11.5;
    discount = 0;
}

void item002(){
    name = "Rice (10kg)";
    price = 25.9;
    discount = 0;
}

void item003(){
    name = "Sugar (1kg)";
    price = 2.95;
    discount = 0;
}

void item_cal(){
    cout << "Please enter the quantity of the item: ";
    cin >> quantity;
    newPrice = (price + (discount * price)) * quantity;
    cout << "\nItem: " << name << "  ||  Quantity: " << quantity << "  ||  Price: RM" << newPrice << endl;
}

void input(){

    cout << "Welcome SA Mart\n" << "Please insert the code. Press 0 to stop: ";

    while (code != 0){
        cin >> code;
        switch (code){
            case 001:
                item001();
                item_cal();
                break;

            case 002:
                item002();
                item_cal();
                break;

            case 003:
                item003();
                item_cal();
                break;

            default:
                cout << "\nWrong code" << endl;;
                break;

        total += newPrice;

        }
    }
}


int main(){
    input();
    totalSST = total * sst;
    grandTotal = total + totalSST;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Total: RM" << total << " ||SST: RM" << totalSST << " || Grand Total: RM" << grandTotal << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you have a suggestion to make my codes look or work better, that would be great.

Comment: Give ` while (cin >> code; && code != 0)` a shot. In English that reads "While we can successfully read into code and code's not zero, process the value in code." Always make sure you read something before you try to use it.

Comment: Suggestion: Death to global variables! Define each variable int he narrowest possible scope and prefer to pass variables into functions over widening the scope. Global variables can break programs more ways than I can count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only functional issue I see in your code is that there is a chance that the code variable will initialize to 0 (depends on the compiler/randomness).  If that happens, your input method will return before it enters the loop.  Other than that it looks like it will work. Of course, programming is not just the art of "making it work," style and readability are important too.  In general, you want to confine variables to the smallest scope in which they are referenced.  'code' should not be a global variable, it should live in the input method.  As for the loop, there are several ways it could be implemented: a "while(true)" loop could be used, in which case the variable may be defined inside the loop; on the other hand a "do while" would guarantee one loop runs (perhaps that would be a good fit here), but the variable must live outside of the loop, at least int the scope of conditional check.  The way you choose is often a matter of style.  Below, I use a "while(true)."

In programming, readability matters (a lot).  I think this program would be easier to read if the data were broken up into a few structs, perhaps "Bill," and "Food."  Another thing to consider is how to broaden the usage of your program, without introducing significant complexity.  For example, it could work for any grocery store (any set of food items/prices).  This is often a matter of determining an appropriate set of parameters to feed your program.
To do these things you might write something like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

namespace market {
    const double& sst = 0.06;

    struct Bill {
        double total = 0;
        double totalSST = 0;
        double grandTotal = 0;
    };

    struct Food {
        const char* name;
        double price;
        double discount;

        Food(const char* name, double price, double discount = 0)
            : name(name), price(price), discount(discount) {}

        double result_price() const {
            return price - price * discount;
        }
    };

    struct GroceryStore {
        const char* name;
        std::map<int, Food> inventory;
        GroceryStore(const char* name, std::map<int, Food> inventory)
            : name(name), inventory(inventory) { }
    };

    void shop(const GroceryStore& store, Bill& bill, bool show_menu = false, int exit_code = 0) {
        // check error conditions
        if (store.inventory.find(exit_code) != store.inventory.end()) {
            // that's the 'exit_code' code silly!
            cout << "Bad store.  Come back another time." << endl;
            return;
        }
        cout << "Welcome to " << store.name << endl;
        if (show_menu) {
            cout << "The following items are available for purchase:" << endl;
            for (auto p : store.inventory) {
                cout << "\t" << p.first << ") " << p.second.name << "(" << p.second.result_price() << endl;
            }
        }
        cout << "Enter the product code of the item you wish to purchase:";
        int code;
        cin >> code;
        while (true) {
            auto food_it = store.inventory.find(code);
            if (food_it == store.inventory.end()) {
                cout << "Thanks for stopping by." << endl;;
                break;
            }
            cout << "Please enter the quantity of the item: ";
            uint32_t quantity;
            cin >> quantity;
            auto& food = food_it->second;
            auto disc_price = food.price - (food.discount * food.price);
            bill.total += disc_price * quantity;
            cout << "\nItem: " << food.name << "  ||  Quantity: " << quantity << "  ||  Price: RM" << disc_price << endl;
            cout << "Would you like anything else?  Enter the product code, or press " << exit_code << " to proceed to check-out." << endl;
            cin >> code;
        }
    }

    void ring_up(Bill& bill) {
        bill.totalSST = bill.total * sst;
        bill.grandTotal = bill.total + bill.totalSST;
    }

    void run() {
        int code = 1;
        GroceryStore store("SMart", {
            { code++, Food("Rice (5kg)", 11.5, 0) },
            { code++, Food("Rice (10kg)", 25.9) },
            { code, Food("Sugar (1kg)", 2.95, 0) }
        });
        Bill bill;
        shop(store, bill, true);
        ring_up(bill);
        cout << "Total: RM" << bill.total << " ||SST: RM" << bill.totalSST << " || Grand Total: RM" << bill.grandTotal << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is a bug in input when u will input 0 then also it won't break while loop as code that is checked contains the previous value.
for example:
 input is 
  3
  0
but according to your code when the code will run the second time and while condition is checked code still contains 3 as value and code will run one more time

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising code to some value, for example, -1. I'm not really sure but I think for global int variables, they initialise int variables to 0. So your first loop doesn't run. Or another way to do it is using do while loops instead of while loop.

```
do {
    cin >> code;
    switch (code){
        case 001:
            item001();
            item_cal();
            break;

        case 002:
            item002();
            item_cal();
            break;

        case 003:
            item003();
            item_cal();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "\nWrong code" << endl;;
            break;

    total += newPrice;

    } while (code != 0);
}
```

This makes sure that the loop will run at least once, making code initialised.
Hope it helps you! Have fun programming!

Comment: I've only been programming for a year and I'm still learning so I'm if I'm wrong, someone please correct me.

Comment: Unfortunately this categorizes 0, a valid input, as "Wrong code". If the input is zero the loop should exit immediately, not after processing zero.